# Asymptote of sine function!

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I am reading about asymptotes in my personal reading. I am thinking not all open curves will have asymptotes as I am not able to comprehend an asymptote for Sine Curve. Is it right/wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, $\sin(x)$ has no asymptote. I'm not sure where you read that every open curve has an asymptote; this is not true.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the above statement is not correct, f(x)=sin(x) does have asymptotes. They are at y=1 and y=-1.

Comment: Not by the usual definition of asymptote, which would require the curve $f(x) = \sin x$ to eventually become arbitrarily close to the line - in fact, no matter how far out you go, there are still places where $f(x)$ is a constant distance away from $y=1$ and $y=-1$.

Comment: In particular, usually we only say that a horizontal line $y=c$ is an asymptote of $f(x)$ if either $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = c$ or $\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = c$, and neither limit exists for $\sin x$.